# Binding to a method which takes a string literal parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In the below code VUE is interpreting "foo" as a function...therefore I get an error foo is not a function, but in fact I just need the string value "foo" passed to my method.

What is the correct syntax please?

```
  <BlokMenu
       :menu="MenuBuilder.filterMenuItems('foo')"
  />
```

[Screen shot of code from my view component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df9k5.png)

and the MenuBuild which is in MenuBuilder.js

[MenuBuilder.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlrXT.png)

Comment: It should be `:menu="MenuBuilder.filterMenuItems('foo')"` (remove `this`)

Comment: That's just the way I've presented the sample code - MenuBuilder is in another module. If I use the syntax you replied with, it's the same as mine, and I get the error foo is not a function.

Comment: Here is another example usage which gives the same error: <BlokMenu :menu="MenuBuilder.filterMenuItems('summary')" /> - and this one says - summary is not a function

Comment: Can you share the filtering logic?

Comment: Can you also please share the error message in full? A screenshot of it in your browser console would be best

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE IN CHROME DEV TOOLS - [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: canvas is not a function"

found in

---> <CanvasView> at src/views/CanvasView.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

Comment: @Phil I don't think the filter logic is relevant as it never gets executed due to the not a function error :(

Comment: I've edited the OP and embeded some screen shots of the code.

Comment: Thanks guys - turns out the error was in my filter code- For example...I wrote "findexIndex(filterTerm)" not "findIndex(item => item.label === filterTerm). Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

`bind` object needs to belong to Vue component itself. In case of external module, you can bind it to `data` or `computed` properties

```
// Vue components

import MenuBuilder from 'MenuBuilder.js'

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      MenuBuilder: MenuBuilder
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
<BlokMenu :menu="MenuBuilder.filterMenuItems('foo')"/>
```

Comment: Yes my code essentially looks like that - but I use inject...so MenuBuilder is passed in from the root object

Comment: Thanks for the contrib - indeed you are correct my syntax in the call was correct - my error was in my filter code :)